# Angular UI-router parent state not active

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i got a problem with parent state not active when child is call.

I'm using ui-router with `ui-sref-active` function.

Here is my router code:

```
.state('customers', {
    abstract: true,
    parent: 'app',
    url: '/customers',
    templateUrl: 'app/customer/parent.html',
})
.state('customers.list', {
    parent: 'customers',
    url: '',
    controller: 'customerCtrl as customer',
    templateUrl: 'app/customer/index.html'
})

.state('customers.birthday', {
    parent: 'customers',
    url: '/birthday',
    templateUrl: 'app/customer/birthday.html',
})
```

Here is my html:

```
 <ul id="menu-sidebar">
    <li class="has_sub">
        <a ui-sref="customers.list" class="waves-effect" ui-sref-active="subdrop">
            <i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span> Customers</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm using ng-repeat because there are plenty of menu.

The problem is when I call `/customers` the `ui-sref-active` is working properly. But when `/customers/birthday` call, ui-sref-active is gone.

Here below screenshot:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Any advice how to make it working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve it.

At my

```
    app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {
      if (to.redirectToChild) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go(to.redirectToChild.state, params)
      }
    });
}]);

 app.config([ '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/404");
    .state('customers', {
        url: '/customers',
        templateUrl: 'app/customer/parent.html',
        redirectToChild: {
                state: 'customers.list'
            },
    })
    .state('customers.list', {
        parent: 'customers',
        url: '',
        controller: 'customerCtrl as customer',
        templateUrl: 'app/customer/index.html'
    })

    .state('customers.birthday', {
        parent: 'customers',
        url: '/birthday',
        templateUrl: 'app/customer/birthday.html',
    })
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be because of how your nesting routes. Try something like this:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('exampleState', {
    url: '/example',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/example/root-view.html',
    controller: 'ParentCtrl'
  })

  .state('exampleState.games', {
    url: '/games',
    views: {
      'stats-games':{
        templateUrl: 'templates/example/firstpage.html',
        controller: 'PageOneCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('exampleState.sesaons', {
    url: '/seasons',
    views: {
      'stats-games':{
      templateUrl: 'templates/example/secondpage.html',
      controller: 'PageTwoCtrl'
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'



    })
    .state('home.main', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'templates/main.html'



    })
    .state('home.owner', {
        url: '/owner',
        templateUrl: 'templates/owner.html'

    })
```

Comment: Sorry but is it really a comma will impact with ui-sref-active? because I usually put comma after an object like that. And I've tried remove it, its no luck :)

Comment: please try this way and dont need to add perent attribute

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/HnwcS1pxd4CbMSNS9EGD maybe it helps you. Can't see any problem with your code

Comment: @trollr I can't any major diffferences with mine. As far as i can tell and tried is my `ui-sref` is point to `customers.list` . when I change it  to only `customers` it working but ofcourse it can't enter the state because its abstract state. any idea?

Comment: @trollr I just realize your plunkr at home you miswirte abstract. Now I fix it and change the <a> ui-sref. Now it just happen like mine. Here is the fix plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/NJRx7RT0TRg04Wbw6kUO?p=preview

Comment: Do you need the abstract state? Would suggest as a workaround to remove abstract, and set the child urls manually to `customers/birthday`. Maybe someone else know the correct solution

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/NJRx7RT0TRg04Wbw6kUO?p=preview                             pls check it